# REST. Subresource of Non-Existent Resource

Tags: rest, http, http-error

I have the following API:

`api/guests/`

`api/guests/{id}/`

`api/guests/{id}/bookings`

Suppose, I'd like to get the bookings of non-existent guest (mean, passing a wrong id)

Should I return `404` error code or just an empty array?

The first option seems to be more restful, however such kind of operations often needs 2 DB calls (1st - for retrieving bookings by `guest_id`, 2nd - checking if the guest exists)

So, which option should I pick up?

Comment: IMHO the correctness is far far more important than a one additional query, fired against the database.

Answer (score 2):

How do you differentiate the two cases :

1. a guest doesn't exist
2. a guest has no bookings

imho, the first one should be notified with a 404, while in the second case you should return an empty array. No matter if it takes two calls to the DB, you can always optimize DB access later. Moreover, designing with performance in mind (i.e. giving privilege to performance w.r.t. "correctness") could bring to "premature optimization".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the semantic you will choose.

IMHO returning 404 means that a specific resource **doesn't** exist - and this differs from "exists but no subresource is given".

Another thing is how you define non-existent - you mean valid but non-existing id or malformed(string instead of a number etc.)?

For the sake of simplicity I always prefer returning an empty collection of items, malformed id is usually validated during model binding so I am sure it is possible to fetch proper data.